# PowerBI: Change type to multiple columns at the same time

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I'm working in the Power Query Editor in Power BI.
I have a table called `Source` where the columns have this order:

```
| Country | Attribute | 2014 | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 | 2021 |
```

You can see the table in the image below:

[image]
I would like to change the column type to every column from "2014" to "2021".
I know it is possible to do that expressing each column separately using the command:

```
= Table.TransformColumnTypes(
    Source,
    {{"2014", type number}, {"2015", type number}, {"2016", type number}, {"2017", type number}, {"2018", type number}, {"2019", type number}, {"2020", type number}, {"2021", type number}}
  )
```

but I would like to set up a command that does that in an automated fashion. I am trying to do something like:

```
= Table.TransformColumnTypes(
    Source,
    each( {List.Range(Table.ColumnNames(Source), 2, List.Count(Table.ColumnNames(Source)) as number),
    type number} )
  )
```

So I am trying to repeat the command `Table.TransformColumnTypes` for "each" value of:

```
List.Range(Table.ColumnNames(Source), 2, List.Count(Table.ColumnNames(Source)) as number)
```

that basically select every column header name in the range from the third column to the last one.

I tried to write it down in many ways, using also `$(...).each(function(...))` or using other `list.` functions but none of them seems to work.

What can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right track with the `Table.ColumnNames` function.

Give this a try:

```
= Table.TransformColumnTypes(
      Source,
      List.Transform(
          List.RemoveFirstN(
              Table.ColumnNames(Source),
              2
          ),
      each {_, type number}
      )
  )
```

The `List.RemoveFirstN` function removes the first `N = 2` columns from your list of column names and then you change each remaining column to `type number`.

Comment: Wooo, this works. So the command each works with the underscore _ to indicate the element?

Anyway thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, the underscore represents the element that the `each` applies to.

Comment: Save my day with this tip !! Thanks !